# Generic Derivation of Parsers with Shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am reading this [blog post](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2015/11/08/type-classes-and-generic-derivation/) about generic derivation of parsers. The post shows how to define `Parser[H :: T]` given `Parser[H]` and `Parser[T]` where `T` is a subtype of `HList`:

```
implicit def hconsParser[H: Parser, T <: HList: Parser]: Parser[H :: T] = 
  new Parser[H :: T] {
    def apply(s: String): Option[H :: T] = s.split(",").toList match {
      case cell +: rest => for {
        head <- implicitly[Parser[H]].apply(cell)
        tail <- implicitly[Parser[T]].apply(rest.mkString(","))
      } yield head :: tail
    }
  }
```

The post defines also `Parser[HNil]` as a base case.

Unfortunately I don't understand how the compiler finds `Parser[T]`. We didn't define a parser `Parser[T]` for `T <: HList`. We defined only `Parser[H :: T]`. Does the compiler know somehow that `Parser[T]` is actually `Parser[H1 :: T1]` ? How does it know that ?

Comment: You can think of what the compiler's doing as building up an inductive proof. If it needs an instance for e.g. `A :: B :: HNil`, it'll ask for one for `B :: HNil`, which will cause a search for one for `HNil`, which we've provided.